# Tomcat doesn't show xforwarded for header client ip

Tags: java, tomcat, http-headers, ip

the accesslog of our tomcat looks like the following:

```
- - - [06/Oct/2017:12:43:03 +0000] "GET /x/static/img/x.png HTTP/1.1" 200 15179 "https://mydomain/subpage/static/css/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Client -> BigIP LB -> Tomcat 7
SSL Termination is on the tomcat end.

I added following lines in the serverxml of tomcat:

```
Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
directory="/tomcat"
prefix="access."
suffix=".log"
pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;"
resolveHosts="false"

Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
internalProxies="10.4.33.144"  #ip of the loadbalancer
remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"cggg
```

Has anybody got an idea why I don't see the clientip's in the log? The referer is correct shown in the log.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve) states: `If used in conjunction with Remote Address/Host valves then this valve should be defined first to ensure that the correct client IP address is presented to the Remote Address/Host valves.` So order of valves matters. Did you test with `RemoteIpValve` in front?

Comment: I just tested it, still no clientip :(